# Why is the maximum value of $x^TAx$ is the largest eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

Given a matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{d \times d}$, why is the following identity true?

$$ \lambda_0 := \max_{x \in \Bbb R^d, \|x\|_2 = 1} x^T A x $$

where $\lambda_0$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Also, does the solution to the above equation has $x$ in the same direction as the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_0$? What connections does the identity have with any of the norms of $A$?

I have tried writing $A$ with its eigen decomposed form, i.e. $A=QDQ^{-1}$ hoping that I would be able to get a form of $y^TDy$ which would mean the RHS can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvalues of $A$. But I am stuck after the first step.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Imagine writing $x$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors.  What happens?

Comment: Is your $A$ matrix symmetric?

Comment: What happens with the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0& 1 \\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ which has no real eigenvalues?

Comment: @IgorRivin I have tried writing $A$ with its eigen decomposed form, i.e. $A=QDQ^{-1}$ hoping that I would be able to get a form of $y^TDy$ which would mean the RHS can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvalues of $A$. But I failed in that attempt.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I tried that. See previous comment. I still failed.

Comment: @BrianBorchers No such assumption.

Comment: @GEdgar Eigen-decomposability is presumed.

Comment: @vicky The identity does **not** hold in general, even if we assume that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is true if $A$ is symmetric as a consequence of the spectral theorem, but it is not true more generally. As an example, consider the diagonalizable matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{34&24\\0&41}.
$$
We have $\lambda_0 = 41$, but the maximum of $x^TAx = 50$ is attained with $x = \frac 15(3,4)^T$.

Comment: I completely agree with your analysis. There is still a lingering doubt that I have. Can you please clarify one more thing? In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11604.pdf), page 20, Eqn. 10, the authors didn't mention anything regarding the type of the matrix that satisfies the above identity. I just want to check if I have made any errors or if I have overlooked something critical.

Comment: @vicky The authors have definitely made a mistake, but the mistake is easily salvageable. They want to use this (incorrect) result to show that if $\|X\|_2 \leq \lambda$, then $v^TXv \leq \lambda \|v\|^2$. This holds without the incorrect result, and this can be shown as follows:
$$
v^TXv \leq \|v\| \cdot \|Xv\| \leq \|v\| \cdot \|X\|_2 \cdot \|v\| \leq \lambda \|v\|^2
$$
where the first two inequalities come from applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the definition of the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm.

Comment: In your proof, is $\|Xv\| \le \|X\|\|v\|$ due to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as well?
For which matrices, do we achieve equality?

Comment: @vicky No, $\|Xv\|\leq \|X\|_2 \cdot \|v\|$ holds due to the definition of the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm. Equality holds if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector associated with the maximum eigenvalue of $X^TX$.

Comment: Last question. Can you recommend me books for learning linear algebra to the depth that you have? Maybe one of each: basic, intermediate and advanced.

Comment: @vicky Off the top of my head: Friedberg Insel and Spence's "Linear Algebra" (should be readable to a motivated mathematics undergraduate student starting from basically the top), Horn and Johnson's "Matrix Analysis" (a handy reference that should be readable to a graduate student with some mathematical maturity), then Rajendra Bhatia's "Matrix Analysis" (which requires more than a little motivation because many of the interesting punchlines are embedded in exercises)

Comment: @vicky That said, keep in mind that I am a researching mathematician who specializes in linear algebra. My understanding of linear algebra comes from years of exposure and practice.